# Send MDNS request with Python Scapy

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, multicast, mdns

I have  device in my LAN that send MDNS that looks like that in Wireshark

```
ip src: 192.168.1.41 , ip dst: 224.0.0.251 , src port : 5353 , dst port : 5353

MDNS    228 Standard query response 0x0000 PTR, cache flush abcd.local PTR, cache flush abcd.local NSEC, cache flush 192.168.1.41.in-addr.arpa NSEC
```

That mean in 192.168.1.41 there is abcd.local.

So I tried to send multicast packet in that LAN to get an answer from 192.168.1.41 with `abcd.local` MDNS

```
from scapy.all import *
sr1(IP()/UDP(dport=5353)/DNS(qd=DNSQR(qtype="PTR", qname="abcd.local")))
```

That packet was sent , but I didn't see any response from 192.168.1.41 , why is that?

Maybe I send wrong MDNS request ?

Comment: I hit the same issue, suggest you try wireshark/tcpdump.
I did figure out that the packet was going out on the wire and a reply was coming back, but I believe it doesn't appear as a reply to sr1 because it comes back from the queried host's IP not the multicast group. 

Also looks like you're not reversing the address properly, ie "192.168.1.41.in-addr.arpa" should be "41.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa"

Comment: Specifically in sendrecv.py::_process_packet it's failing the "if h in self.hsent" check on the reply